# select options not displaying using functions

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to displays value of selects options dynamically in PHP. Basically user creates those options awhich are stored in database and then I am trying to fetch this at different place. for this purpose i wrote the below function:

```
function fetch_acad_yr($conn) { 
    $query = "SELECT a.fk_acadyear_id as acadyearid,b.acad_year as acadyear FROM tbl_admparam a inner join list_acad_years b on a.fk_acadyear_id = b.pk_acad_year_id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        foreach ($stmt as $row) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['acadyearid'] ?>"><?php echo $row['acadyear'] ?></option>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

then in html i called this function

```
<select class="form-control" id="acad_period" name="acad_period" required>
<option value="">Please select...</option>
 <?php fetch_acad_yr($conn); ?>
 </select>
```

But the options doent show any values it simply come blank and is not dispalying the values stored in database. I tried running the query separately and the query is returning the desired result

Comment: Are you getting data from the query?

Comment: @PankajMakwana yes query is reuturning the right values

Comment: @AnandhuNadesh I am using the function all over in the application and all of thema re working fine. I am not able to understand why is the issue with this one

Comment: @AnandhuNadesh — If the values are printing *in the function* then they get sent to the output stream at the time the function is called. There's no need to return them.

Comment: Please try checking the `$stmt` value returned from `execute()` for errors, and let us know what you get.

Comment: @O.Jones its simply printing the entire form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
if ($con->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

?>
<select name="acad_period" required="">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <?php
    $s= "SELECT a.fk_acadyear_id as acadyearid,b.acad_year as acadyear FROM tbl_admparam a inner join list_acad_years b on a.fk_acadyear_id = b.pk_acad_year_id";
    $ex= $con->query($s);
    if (!$ex)
      {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
      }
      else
      {
        while ($f= $ex->fetch_assoc())
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $f['acadyearid'] ?>"><?php echo $f['acadyear'] ?></option>
            <?php
            # code...
        }
      }
    
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right connection and the data coming in the query result. 
Basic php mysql code I used was the below and it worked. You make change it to pdo or propel and get the result. But the usage is same with while or for loop.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

echo "<pre>";
echo "<select>";
fetch_acad_yr($conn);
echo "<\select>";

function fetch_acad_yr($conn) { 
    $query = "SELECT a.fk_acadyear_id as acadyearid,b.acad_year as acadyear FROM tbl_admparam a inner join list_acad_years b on a.fk_acadyear_id = b.pk_acad_year_id";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['acadyearid'] ?>"><?php echo $row['acadyear'] ?></option>
            <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Works for me.